# Promise catch not intercepting the exception

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I have written a catch for my promise but it doesn't seem to intercept the exception thrown by the .net core api. As you can see in the code below, I am sending an exception from my api.
The catch block never gets executed even if the exception is thrown from the api.
I am not sure what the problem could be

Angular component

```
private getRepCode = (repCode: string) => {
    this.loading = true;
    const repToSend = fromGenistarCode(repCode);
    if (repToSend === 0) {
      this.splitSaleDetails.repName = '';
      return;
    }
    this.inviteService.getRepApprovedName(repToSend, this.currentUserId).then(rep => {
      if (rep) {
        this.splitSaleDetails.repName = rep.name;
      } else {
        this.splitSaleDetails.repName = '';
      }
      this.fieldDataChanged(new SetSplitSaleDetails(this.splitSaleDetails));
      this.loading = false;
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      return this.messageService.add(err.message, 'warning', true);
    });
```

Angular service

```
  public getRepApprovedName = (repId: number, loggedInUserId: number): Promise<any> =>
    this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}representative-name/${repId}/${loggedInUserId}`).toPromise()
```

.Net API

```
[FunctionName(nameof(GetRepresentativeName))]
        [UsedImplicitly]
        public Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "organisation/representative-name/{id}/{loggedInId}")]
            HttpRequest req,
            int id, int loggedInId) => _helper.HandleAsync(async () =>
            {
                await _helper.ValidateRequestAsync(req);

                var person = await _context.Person
                    .Include(x => x.Representative)
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id
                                                           && x.Id != loggedInId
                                                           && x.Representative.ApprovalDateTime != null
                                                           && x.Representative.PaymentDateTime != null 
                                                           && x.Representative.TerminatedDateTime == null);

                return person != null
                    ? (IActionResult)new OkObjectResult(new
                    {
                        name = $"{person.FirstName} {person.LastName}"
                    })
                    : new NotFoundObjectResult(new JsonError { Message = @"<html><body>
                                                                            <ul> 
                                                                                <li>You cannot split a sale with Yourself</li>            
                                                                                <li>A representative that has not completed their IBA and not been approved by compliance.</li>
                                                                                <li>A terminated representative.</li>
                                                                            </ul>
                                                                            </body></html>", Name = nameof(InvalidOperationException) });

            });
    }
```

Comment: Probably coz you are not returning the API in `getRepApprovedName()`

Comment: But as you can see the  getRepApprovedName is calling the endpoint. I have debugged the code and can see the api being called

Comment: What's the response status in the Chrome devtools network tab?

Comment: The response is  {"name":"InvalidOperationException","message":"<html><body>\r\n  <ul> \r\n <li>You cannot split a sale with Yourself</li> \r\n <li>A representative that has not completed their IBA and not been approved by compliance.</li>\r\n  <li>A terminated representative.</li>\r\n     </ul>\r\n    /body></html>","stack":null}

Comment: status code 404 Not Found

Comment: That could be because I am setting the excption type as NotFoundObjectResult in the api

Comment: If in the network the http call is of type 404 the angular client will not catch anything. If you change it to give you a 500 (for example) it will be catched in the `.catch`

Comment: @Tom if you don't return a promise, your promise gets broken. Add a return the http call, something like: `return this.http.get...`

Comment: I am getting a syntax error when adding keyword return. It says brace bracket missing

Comment: @Tom I am sorry, I see there's an implicit return, I didn't realize that you are using an arrow function without brackets. Then the problem is something else.